# Property File doesnt work

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, properties, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to find a way, how to use a properties file in my Java Servlet (extends http-servlet). I've tried out to use `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()` and `ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`. But whatever I'm doing, nothing works and there is always a `NullPointerException`.

`database.properties` File:

```
Driver=org.postgresql.Driver
Protokoll=jdbc:postgresql://
Speicherort=localhost/
Datenbank=Ticketshop
User=postgres
```

code:

```
p = new Properties();
p.load(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/properties/database.properties"));
protokoll = p.getProperty("Protokoll");
speicherort = p.getProperty("Speicherort");
user = p.getProperty("User");
driver = p.getProperty("Driver");
password = p.getProperty("Password");
database = p.getProperty("Datenbank");
```

file-tree:

```
Java Resources
  |-- src
     |-- login
        |-- Login.java
WebContent
  |-- WEB-INF
     |-- properties
        |-- database.properties
```

Comment: Please include the exception in your question.

Comment: which line throw null pointer exception ?

Comment: I get the error in that line, in which I'm loading the properties into variable p --> p.load(...);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `ResourceBundle`. It is so simple to use. **Place properties file in the source folder**, and

```
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class DatabaseConstantsAccessor
{
    // don't include .properties extension, just specify the name without extension
    private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "database";

    private static final ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME);

    private ConstantsAccessor()
    {
    }

    public static String getString(String key)
    {
        try
        {
            return RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key);
        }
        catch (MissingResourceException e)
        {
            return '!' + key + '!';
        }
    }
}
```

And where you want to access properties, use following code:

```
String driverString=DatabaseConstantsAccessor.getString("Driver");
Integer intProp=Integer.valueOf(DatabaseConstantsAccessor.getString("SomeIntProperty"));
```

Comment: okay. I tried your code, but I still get an "HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class login.Login".                                                       SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Login
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name database, locale de_AT

Comment: @Maexwell Please make sure that **database.properties** file is placed in **src** folder. If still things don't work out, then change the initialization call as follows: `private static final ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME,"");`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! it is working now :-)  (I've made the mistake to place the property-file in the package, not just in the src-folder...)  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

check all names. your code is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

**Edit**

```
p.load(getServletContext().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("properties/database.properties"));
```

And BTW you need to `move the database.properties` to `/WEB-INF/classes` folder for this to work

**The Folder structure should be**

```
WEB-INF
  | classes
      |properties
       database.properties
```

Comment: nope. nothing... do I have to edit anything in web.xml??               java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:125)
 at login.Login.<init>(Login.java:23)

Comment: --> Login.java:23 is the line loading properties into p

Comment: Can you tell me how you are executing it - from Eclipse Server plugin / or building a war and deploying to a standalone server

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and a Tomcat Server. Just clicking the button "Run Login.java" ;-) Am i to run try it on a standalone server?

Comment: Shouldnt it be 'Run on Server' , i hope its a Dynamic Web Project ?

Comment: yes of course! it is one ;-) after clicking the button i can choose to run it on the server... i've built a war-file and depolyed it on the server. the same result: a NullPointerException (in that line, where i call the p.load-method).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with "dj aqeel" but to get a ResourceBundle, this must be in the class directory.

Thus, I put the file in "/WEB-INF/**classes**/properties/database.properties". Obviously, you must put the file in the src directory and the compiler move there automatically.

Marcos

Comment: thanks! but i still get the same error as using it without /classes